# Copy one column value to another in CSV when other column values has comma inside quotes in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, awk

Input CSV Sample

```
name,mobile,address,usermobile
Testone, 111111111, "test,address"
Testtwo, 2222222222, "Testtwo,address"
```

Now I want to copy mobile column value into usermobile column. But there is a comma(,) inside  address column although it is inside double quotes but I am not getting expected output

Expected Output

```
name,mobile,address,usermobile
Testone, 111111111, "test,address",111111111
Testtwo, 2222222222, "Testtwo,address",2222222222
```

I have tried this by using below command but not getting expected output

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" && FS=OFS=","} (NR>1) && ($2!=""){$5=$2} 1' test.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```
awk 'NR>1{$(NF+1)=$2} {print}' FS=', ' OFS=', ' file
```

Output:

```
name,mobile,address,usermobile
Testone, 111111111, "test, address", 111111111
Testtwo, 2222222222, "Testtwo, address", 2222222222
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, **OFS**, RS, ORS, **NR**, **NF**, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: I am  getting this output from your command. only comma is getting added at end
name,mobile,address,usermobile
Testone,111111111,"test,address",, 
Testtwo,2222222222,"Testtwo,address",,

Comment: @user13000875; based on the sample input data from the question, I get the same output as Cyrus (and which matches the desired output in the question)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. I have written this on mobile so couldn't test it should work though in GNU `awk`

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' -v OFS=", " 'FNR==1{print;next} {print $0,$2}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` a more legible code can be setting at the beginning  the same for FS and OFS `", "` (comma followed by space) and then print what you need: `$2` at the end in this case.

`awk -v FS=", " -v OFS=", " 'NF==1 {print}; NF>1 {print $1, $2, $3, $2}' file`

```
name,mobile,address,usermobile
Testone, 111111111, "test,address", 111111111
Testtwo, 2222222222, "Testtwo,address", 2222222222
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier with a more modern and more powerful tool like Ruby, which can do everything that awk can do and can do what awk cannot do.

```
$ cat ... | ruby -ne $'require "csv"; print $_.chop() + "," + CSV.parse($_)[0][1] + "\n" if not $_.match(/name,mobile/)'
Testone,111111111,"test, address",111111111
Testtwo,2222222222,"Testtwo, address",2222222222
```

NB: According to the standard, the CSV file should not contain spaces between fields, i.e. the input file should be like this:

```
Testone,111111111,"test,address"
Testtwo,2222222222,"Testtwo,address"
```